# First click anywhere redirects somewhere and 2nd click to the destination how to do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, hyperlink, onclick

on click adds are popular nowdays but i want to make a script which do same like their codes where on each page 1st click will open a new tab with another webpage some custom address and the second will takes the user to their destination . a sample onclick ads code given below

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//vebadu.com/apu.php?zoneid=1415303'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
                           //set href for all links=>stackoverflow
 $('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href','https://stackoverflow.com');
 });

 var click_counter=0;                //counter of click
 $('a').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){            //timeout for open link
      click_counter++;                //first click => 1
      if(click_counter==1){
        $('a').each(function(){
                               //replace all hrefs
        var second_link=$(this).attr('second-link');
        $(this).attr('href', second_link);
       });
      }
  },500);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a href=""  target="_blank" second-link="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a><br>
<a href=""  target="_blank" second-link="https://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia</a><br>
<a href=""  target="_blank" second-link="https://www.amazon.com">amazon</a><br>
<a href=""  target="_blank" second-link="https://www.gm.com">General Motors</a><br>
```